# Code got executed while running unit test but it shows not covered

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, sonarqube, karma-runner

I have a custom async validator which validate location
`newStopControl:new FormControl('',[Validators.required],[this.validateLocation()]`
on success validation it calls another function which populates value to few input fields.

```
validateLocation() {
  this.locationservice.isValid().subscribe(res => {
    if(res) {
      this.populateTime()
    }
  })
}
```

and based on some condition populateTime function calls another function.

```
populateTime() {
  this.addform.patchValue({time:someValue})
  if(someValue) {
    this.populateDate();
  }
}
```

all functions are executing while test and covered as well but the last function i.e **populatedate**() shows not covered even it is executing.

Comment: Could it not be covered because `someValue` is false and therefore it doesn't go inside of the `if` statement?

Comment: Its going inside and executing almost each line of code.